# Modifying URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have the following script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $.getScript("http://www.anrdoezrs.net/am/7825092/include/allCj/generate/onLoad/am.js", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
            window.location =  $('#cjlink').attr('href');
    }, 500);

        });

    });
```

which is basically supposed to redirect to the link generated by am.js.
I would like to modify the link generated by the am.js so it will replace domain34.com/us or domain34.com/ with domain34.com/uk

I tried htaccess but could not find a way to rewrite outgoing urls
i need some method via php or js.

Comment: You can just use a regex and replace part of the URL.

Comment: You may not even have to use regexes. It all depends on what is fixed and what is variable in your URL. Thats what is missing from your question.

Comment: How do I do it with regex? It's a specific domain I want to modify

Comment: @SammyMiri you could just use `str_replace`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Ajax.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) documentation, you should pass the **data** argument, then add js replace [insert adresse here] you wich to get redirected.

As asked by the OP. Not tested code thou, the js file could not be loaded for some reason:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript("http://www.anrdoezrs.net/am/7825092/include/allCj/generate/onLoad/am.js", function(data){
        data = data.replace('domain34.com/us', 'domain34.com/uk');
        data = data.replace('domain34.com/', 'domain34.com/uk');
        window.location.replace(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: hi inaliahgle. can you post an example

Comment: @SammyMiri exemple provided as requested, i hope that meets your question. please accept the answer if it was the case.

Comment: hey inaliahgle. thanks for the example. but i need it to work while keeping the setTimeout function and window.location =  $('#cjlink').attr('href'); intact.. the scripit mostly produces completely different domain urls which wont be specified in the "data.replace"